# Connection between microservices written in different languages

Tags: python, flask, proxy, docker-compose, microservices

I have a small web app that uses 3 microservices. HomeApp is written in Flask and serves the home page and login page. WebApp serves user profile and orders/products. Last one is a mysql database. I have dockerised them and use docker-compose to run them simultaneously. I'm trying to figure out a way to redirect a user from HomeApp to WebApp inside Flask. Is it possible to do so by simply using the service name created by docker-compose or would I need some proxy like nginx or envoy?
Here's what I'm thinking about:
HomeApp:

```
def login():
web = os.getenv['web']
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    usernamedata = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username",{"username": username}).fetchone()
    passworddata = db.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username",{"username": username}).fetchone()

    if usernamedata == None:
        render_template('login.html')
    else:
        for password_data in passworddata:
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password, password_data):
                  return redirect(web + "/user?=" + username)
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: go_test
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    ports: 
      - "80:80"

  mysql:
    image: mysql_db
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"

  flask:
    image: flask_app
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
```

web would be the WebApp service written in Golang. Would it work the way I want to do this or should I just place a proxy between services?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible what you want to do, if you use docker's `links` option.
like :

```
flask:
    image: flask_app
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - "web:web"
```

Then you can access directly to `web` in your python code.

Because docker's `links` option makes `etc/hosts` like :

```
172.0.0.3 web // example
```

So, you don't need input `web = os.getenv['web']` in your code.

> See :
>
> *Containers for the linked service are reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.*
>
> Here's [a document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) about docker `links` option.

Comment: Tried this now, still doesn't work. I get `name 'web' is not defined` and in hosts file I get container id instead of web

Comment: then try `links: - "web:web"`

Comment: I'm on version 3 so `- web` should work but it doesn't.